# java newbie: reading in a file for word search code. .add() and .toArray() is giving me errors

Tags: java, bufferedreader, wordsearch

I'm really trying to figure out what's wrong with this code. The .add() and .toArray() have red lines underneath them. Is there some kind of alternative to writing those two lines? What am I doing wrong?

```
package prog3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class WordList {

    private String filename;
    private Word[] words;

    public WordList(String fileName) {
        this.filename = fileName;
    }

    //reads in list of words and stores them internally. line by line 
    //if method reas list of words successfully, then it returns as true, otherwise false

    public boolean readFile() {

        try{
            BufferedReader read;
            read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = read.readLine())!= null) {
                nextLine = nextLine.trim();
                read.add(new Word(nextLine));
            }

            words = read.toArray(new Word[0]);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " +ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

//getList is supposed to return the list of words as an array of class Word. How do I do this???

public Word[] getList() {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error given when you mouse over the red lines?

Comment: cannot find symbol symbol: method toArray(Word[]))
location: variable read of type BufferedReader

Comment: You need to call `add(` on an ArrayList, not a buffered reader.

Comment: If I am not wrong then you want to add those lines to some kinda of `list`

Comment: Make a `List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>()` then `words.add(new Word...`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `add(` on a BufferedReader, which is impossible.

Instead, create an arrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

Then add with:

```
list.add(read.readLine());
```

Then call toArray with the list when done.

I'm not going into the use of the Word class as we're working with lines of text, not words.

Comment: when you say "call toArray with the list" what does that mean in terms of code?

Comment: you mean 'list.toArray(new Word[0])'?

Comment: No, with an array of String objects. We're not dealing with words as we're reading line by line.

Comment: I'm really not understanding what that should look like.

Comment: `list.toArray(new String[0])` @DanielleElizabeth.

Comment: I fixed it with one line--> list.add(new Word(nextLine));

Answer (score 1):

`read` is a `BufferedReader`, which doesn't have `.add()` and `.toArray()` methods. Check out the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Perhaps you want to add the items into an array or an arraylist.

Comment: I removed the lines that were giving me errors and I added list.add(read.readLine()); 
but how do I call toArray with the list when done. I'm not sure as to what code I should be using

Comment: If you have an ArrayList called `list`, you can just say `list.toArray()` and your ArrayList will be converted to an array. Once again, I suggest looking at the documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html